# How to write a correct D3 string for a custom Metric in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I just created a simple table in apache superset, which contains different columns. And i have a two columns, which shows:

1. amount of bytes
2. rows count

But superset shows them similar:

- column of bytes shows like `461G`
- column of rows count also shows like `1.8G`

It may confuse users, and i want to show a rows count like `1.8B`.

In manual is written, that i can create my own metric with needed format, using D3 syntax - https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#format. But i can't understand how to write it correctly.

Can you show me example of a d3 string to change `1.8G` to `1.8B` or `1.800.000.000`?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just type ".01s" into the D3 entry in your metric setup. This will give you 1.8B for 1,800,000,000 and 1.0B for 1,000,000,000